# Is the difference between programming model wrt Program Counter and Stack Pointer in case of Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, mips, program-counter, stack-pointer

**Processor model I**

```
 ● Registers  
    PC – Program Counter  
    Single data register (accumulator) without name  
    We will use symbol A to describe operations on this register  
 ● Stack with an unspecified implementation  
 ● Data specified by name or value  
    More realistic model will follow later 

  Instruction     Action         Description  
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  load data       A = data       Load data to accumulator  
  store data      data = A       Store data from accumulator to memory  
  add data        A += data      Add data to accumulator  
  push data                      Push data onto stack  
  call addr       Push PC        Jump and store return trace on the stack 
                  PC = addr
                  Pop PC 
  return          Pop PC         Return – jump to the previously stored trace addr  
  create data                    Allocate data on stack  
  destroy data                   Deallocate data from stack
```

**Processor model II**

```
● More realistic version of model I  
● Stack explicitly implemented in memory  
● Stack Pointer register - SP  
● Stack operations defined explicitly using SP  
● Allocation and deallocation of local data implemented 
   by changing the value of SP (no data transfer occurs)
● Arguments and local variables accessed by names  
    Still unrealistic  

  Instruction    Action               Description
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  load data      A = data             Load data to accumulator (constant or variable)
  store data     data = A             Store data from accumulator to memory
  add data       A += data            Add data to accumulator (constant of variable)
  push data      *--SP = data         Place data on the stack (constant of variable)
  call addr      *--SP = data         Jump storing the return trace on the stack
                 PC = addr            
  return         PC = *SP++           Return to the previously stored trace address
  Create data    SP -= sizeof(data)   Allocate data on the stack
  Destroy data   SP += sizeof(data)   Deallocate data from the stack
```

The above two slides were presented during a lecture wrt x86/MIPS. I haven't understood much.

Only thing I understood is, there are two models of calling functions using stacks, and allocating/freeing heaps. One uses PC and another uses SP.

Is it talking about models for two different processors (x86/MIPS)? Which one is for whom?

Can anyone kindly explain?

Comment: In model I: **A call should not pop the PC**. A return does, and if the call would do that too, it would be gone when the sub returns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are x86-like, where `call` pushes a return address (PC) onto the stack.  Note that PC during execution of the `call` instruction points to the end of the instruction / start of the next, so PC is the address of the instruction that should execute after `ret` from a `call`.

The 2nd model is just more explicit about how the stack works, matching x86 [`push`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/push)/`pop`/`call`/`ret`.  That's *all* it changed.

MIPS `jal` puts a return address into a register (the link register `$lr` is one of the 32 general-purpose integer regs on MIPS).  Software can push it on the stack manually (e.g. in non-leaf functions), but the ISA doesn't know/care about that.

MIPS doesn't even architecturally have a "stack pointer" that's used implicitly for anything.  A callstack is a software convention, although a very useful one that essentially all software *does* use in basically the same way as x86, just without single instructions that combine modifying SP and load or store.

> Only thing I understood is, there are two models of calling functions using stacks, and allocating/freeing heaps. One uses PC and another uses SP.

**No, this is completely wrong on all levels.**

First of all, none of the examples show anything about heap memory, only reserving space for local variables (automatic storage) in the stack.  Storage that will be released when a function returns.

"Heap" memory is separate.  It's not usually a single thing, e.g. static and dynamic allocation are usually separate in modern OSes.  But anyway, dynamic heap allocation like `malloc` will give you a pointer to memory that is still valid after `add sp, 16` or whatever and `ret` to tear down the current function's stack frame.

**And 2nd, PC is not involved at all in allocation of storage**.  The details only show PC being read as a return address, and written by jump/call/ret instructions.  It's also known as IP, the instruction pointer.  On x86, the 32 and 64-bit versions of the IP register are EIP / RIP respectively.

Comment: Could you kindly add some compilable  example  codes for both of the models so that I can experiment with them?

Comment: @user366312: SO's [tag:x86] and [tag:mips] tags are full of examples.  Or look at C compiler output for some simple functions on Godbolt: [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)